What does it mean if the ST-LINK/V2 LED doesn't stop blinking red and green after the code is uploaded successfully to the MCU?
I have used the ST-LINK/V2 plenty of times and from what I have noticed, while the code from STM32cubeIDE is downloading on the MCU, the ST-LINK LED is blinking red and green and it stops once the code is uploaded. With this PCB for some reason the blinking doesn't stop once the code finished uploading and I also ran into some problems. I have a blue LED on the PCB that I programmed to blink, but the LED is very dim or it doesn't work at all and the weird part is once I connect the two terminals of the digital multimeter to the blue LED ends, the LED starts blinking. From what I have seen the ST-LINK/V2 and the STM32F405RGT6 work on 3.3V, but my buck converter outputs ~3.6V so I am wondering if this has anything to do with my problems. Any insight is very helpful!




